# Flex List with Texts of different size

Tags: apache-flex, list, text

I have an ArrayCollection named authors with lot of texts of different size. I would like to list all info about authors in a way that each item has a size according to the text. Here is the code:

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{authors}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox width="100%">
                <mx:Text text="{data.name}"/>
                <mx:Text text="{data.about}" width="100%"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

I have tried many different things but nothing helped. Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{authors}" height="300" variableRowHeight="true" width="200">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0">
                <mx:Text text="{data.name}" />
                <mx:Text text="{data.about}" width="{explicitWidth}" />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

Comment: Thanks the variableRowHeight was the issue and the width="{explicitWidth}" was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the fontSize attribute?

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{authors}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:VBox width="100%">
                <mx:Text text="{data.name}" fontSize='30'/>
                <mx:Text text="{data.about}" width="100%"/>
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

Alternatively, using the htmlText property will allow you to format the text with HTML: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Comment: The 'name' field is ok, my problem is that the 'about' field has many lines of text, sometimes 1 sometimes 7 etc and I need to have the height of the Item according to that height of the text.

Comment: Also autoSize=True, see http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=60414